# unable to reset the values back to the originally selected values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am working on bootstrap datepicker, i have a Reset and submit buttons on the datepicker.
I want to implement the Reset button functionality to one of the buttons on the datepicker.When user selects the new date range from the calendar and click on Reset button, the previously (originally) selected values should be highlighted and the newly selected values should be cleared.

Please find the code demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cuC1q934UmEWNyUs6gQh?p=preview)

Initially when clicked in the Select Date filed, a calendar is opened and dates 04/23/2017 as start date and 06/07/2017 date as end date are selected.When user selects other date range , the newly selected dates are highlighted. When user click on Reset button, again it has to show the originally selected dates (04/23/2017 and 06/07/2017) highlighted( basically we are clearing off the newly selected values so that user can select other date range).

I have gone through the API but unable to get the expected output.

I tried something as below

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
  locale: { cancelLabel: 'Reset' }  
});

$('#reportrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  //do something, like clearing an input
  $('#reportrange').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar trouble and the following worked for me:

```
   $('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
```

Both method calls were needed, otherwise it didn't clear.

Comment: Please find the updated code demo http://plnkr.co/edit/K2xf64enDmxhgVeLXUgG?p=preview . It's resettng the value but the newly selected dates are still highlighted, i want the highlight of the dates also to show the originally selected values when clicked on Reset button.Please suggest.